# mongodb: check user/password with c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, authentication

in my c#-project I'm using MongoDB with the official c#-driver.
I'm using always the admin-connection to execute the queries/udpates/inserts on the mongodb and handle all the authentication and authorization in my webservice (which will pass the commands to the mongodb if allowed).

My question is:
how can I check user-credentials? I just want to know, if the user and password-combination is valid in mongodb.

in command-line there is a db.auth(), but with the c# driver I couldn't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is official manual: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/authenticate-with-csharp-driver/

If auth process fails,you can catch   MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException.

Comment: first of all thanks for your fast answer. but in which cases will he throw this exception. when I provide incorrect user/password nothing happens. do I have to call a specific method on the client-object?

Comment: ok I added the following and that worked (it throws an MongoConnectionException): var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);               mongoClient.GetServer().Connect(); this will throw an exception. In which situation will it throw a MongoAuthenticationException? I think this would be the better way to handle this type of error.

Comment: Yes if you dont call connect() , connection will not begin until operation methods like find() or other are called.

Comment: I think I found a better way if you just want to check if credentials are valid. I now use a ping: var connection = client.GetServer();
connection.Ping(); this will throw a MongoAuthenticationException if the credentials are not correct.