# Is there a way to authenticate a MongoDB user before connection in a C# WinForm?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, winforms, authentication

I'm playing with building a MongoDB Explorer in a Windows Form specific to our implementation and I'm looking for the C# equivalent of db.Auth(). I've found this here:

[mongodb: check user/password with c# driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314993/mongodb-check-user-password-with-c-sharp-driver)

It mentions the Authentication section of the MongoDB documentation, but little else and the question is 7 years old.
Comments there mention Client.GetServer, but that's deprecated and gone.
I can try to list databases or the like, but all that gets me is a TimeOut exception.

I built this out and it works, but seems a bit backwards:

```
    public bool Authenticate(string userName, string password)
    {
        bool auth = false;
        ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\yada\blah\mongo.exe")
        {
            Arguments = $" blah--authenticationDatabase admin -u {userName} -p {password}",
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        };
        Process process = new Process();

        process.StartInfo = si;
        process.Start();

        while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            if (output.StartsWith("Implicit session"))
            {
                process.Kill();
                auth = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return auth;
    }
```

Comment: Rather than launching an external exe...have you considered just attempting to connect to the database with the credentials and seeing if an exception is thrown or not?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C# .NET, it's a call of an external `.exe`. See [MongoDB C#/.NET Driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/csharp/) how to connect to a MonogDB from .NET